# Permission file error when save options in admin panel

Tags: error, admin-panel, magento2.1.6, file-permissions, production-mode

I have a problem with the **Magento administrator**, when I try to save any changes that are inside

> Content > Settings or Content > Blocks

I get the following error and could not correct it.

I already changed the permissions and I do not know what else to do.

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

### Additional information

- PHP version 7.0
- Apache 2.2.31
- Magento 2.1.6

Please, what should I do?

### Image of error

[image: Image error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that your user have the ownership of the files
Use this command to give ownership of the files to your user

```
chown $USER -R ~/.blabla
```

Also set the permission 777 for var folder, and test it.

Comment: I already tried and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to reach the solution.
The first time execute the following command:
Chown $ USER -R <path to Magento dir>/ 

But he still had the same problem, then try the following:
Chown $ USER -R <path to Magento dir>/ *

Now everything is working, for now I have no more difficulties, thanks again.